# MySQL: Out of range when copying data to table created using LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a script analyzing data from the `mysql.slow_log` table. For these purposes I need to copy some rows I'm interested in into another, temporary table, so I'm going like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.slow_log_to_analyze LIKE mysql.slow_log;
TRUNCATE TABLE test.slow_log_to_analyze;

INSERT INTO test.slow_log_to_analyze
  SELECT * FROM mysql.slow_log WHERE start_time < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE);
```

Unfortunately, the last command throws an error:

```
Error Code: 1264. Out of range value for column 'query_time' at row 1
```

Structures of the slow_log and the other table are supposed to be identical, so this does not make sense any to me. What's the problem?

I'm using MySQL 5.5.39.0.

*EDIT:* The table `test.slow_log_to_analyze` is *always* created using `... LIKE mysql.slow_log`, so there's no reason for it to have different structure.

Comment: seems like the table is incorrect - drop the table(slow_log_to_analyze) then run the script ?

Comment: No, the table is always created using `... LIKE mysql.slow_log` and thus has to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

The keywords `IF NOT EXISTS` prevent an error from occurring if the table exists. However, there is no verification that the existing table has a structure identical to that indicated by the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

It seems simpler to do the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test.slow_log_to_analyze;
CREATE TABLE test.slow_log_to_analyze SELECT * FROM mysql.slow_log;
```

Comment: I can't do this. The code in the question is a part of an event handler and the `test.slow_log_to_analyze` table has a trigger on it (which cannot be recreated from within the handler). The `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...` part is there just to avoid errors in case the table does not exist for some reason.

Comment: Are you free to try some things out? I'm curious if you get any errors if you run the above code, could do so by writing to another table (e.g. test.test123). Have you checked the schema of the table you're selecting from - do the datatypes for column 1 actually match? What is the trigger on the table doing, any chance it's interfering?

Comment: The schema is identical, the column is of the `time` type. The trigger runs after insertion. It selects each newly added row and attempts to find value of one of its fields (`sql_text`) in different table. The trigger makes no changes to the `test.slow_log_to_analyze` table.

Comment: Oh my god. It's the trigger. I tried to detach it and the error disappeared. Thank you for your comments, they were actually very helpful.

Comment: Cool, glad you got it. :)